# How to block Watir ruby gem activities in a site?

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, screen-scraping, watir

I'm a webmaster and I'm trying out Watir ruby gem that controls actions of a browser.

I know that a lot of developers use Watir for testing but I also see the use of Watir to scrape content from websites.

I wonder as a webmaster, can I detect such usage? Can I also detect that the **scraper** is using Watir?

Also how can I stop Watir?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if you could detect if there is a human or a Watir script behind the browser visiting your site. Watir drives real browsers, so filtering by user agent would not help.

If you have a tool that allows you to monitor traffic in real time, you could detect screen scraping by a lot of traffic to the same IP. You could then (temporarily) block the IP.

At the moment I can not think about any other way to block screen scraping. Files like `robots.txt` are just a convention, the script can ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

You might be detect if someone scrapes your site if you monitor the usage of that user - if the user is doing things very fast then it's probably a robot.

You cannot detect however if the scraper is using Watir or any other scraping tool.